# Странные заголовки от sendmail или apache: Received: (from www-data@localhost)

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, smtp, sendmail

Награда: 100 WMR/QIWI/YM

Есть небольшая проблема с `sendmail` & `php` (функция `mail`). Почта отправляется, но отсутствует загловок `Return-Path:`, хотя в `php` я его добавил. И присутствуют непонятные зоголовки `Received:`. А это `www-data@localhost` && `from mysite.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])`.

**Далее**

**mysite.com** - *Мой домен*

**666.666.666.666** - *IP моего VPS*

---

**Заголовки письма**

```
Received: from mysite.com (mysite.com [666.666.666.666])
  by harakamonstr.temp-mail.org (Haraka/2.8.8) with ESMTP id XXXXXXXX
  envelope-from <tester@mysite.com>;
  Mon, 03 Oct 2016 06:33:25 -0400
Received: from mysite.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
  by mysite.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4.1ubuntu1) with ESMTP id xXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  for <cugab@cartelera.org>; Mon, 3 Oct 2016 14:32:29 +0400
DKIM-Signature: ...
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
  by mysite.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id xXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
  Mon, 3 Oct 2016 14:32:29 +0400
X-Authentication-Warning: mysite.com: www-data set sender to tester@mysite.com using -f
To: cugab@cartelera.org
Subject: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: ...
Message-id: ...
Date: ...
Content-Type: ...
X-Mailer: ...
```

В итоге письма летят в спам. Сервис `mail-tester.com` говорит, что у меня не настроеный обратный DNS на ip. Думает, что записи RTC нет. Вывод команды `nslookup 666.666.666.666`:

**nslookup 666.666.666.666**

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
666.666.666.666.in-addr.arpa       name = mysite.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

**Кусок php кода**

```
$headers = "From: tester@mysite.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: tester@mysite.com";

mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f' . $from );
```

**php.ini** *[mail function]*

```
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
mail.add_x_headers = Off
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain mysite.com
127.0.0.1 mysite.com www.mysite.com
```

**/etc/hostname**

```
mysite.com
```

**/etc/mail/local-host-names**

```
localhost
mysite.com
```

Конфиги `sendmail` стоят по умолчанию, какие были при скачивании. За исключением пару строк для `opendkim`.

Как сделать, чтобы в заголовка не показывался `localhost`, `www-data@localhost`, `127.0.0.1` и был заголовок `Return-Path:`?

**Сервер**

- php5
- apache
- sendmail
- opendkim
     ubuntu 14.04

Comment: А если дописать к `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` ключ `-ftester@mysite.com` (То что написано слитно - не опечатка) прям в php.ini в [mail function]?

Comment: @nobody, заголовки так и остались за исключением того, что sendmail сейчас не добавляет `X-Authentication-Warning`. Почтовики по прежднему не видят rDNS

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Проблема не решена, но есть другая: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575317/500-wmr-ya-qiwi-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D1%8B-php