# Настройка отправки почты PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, exim

Не получается грамотно отправить почту в связке:

- функция mail() в PHP
- exim4
- ubuntu 14.04

**Кусок кода на php**

```
mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f' . $from );
// В $headers есть заголовки: From, Reply-To, Return-Path
```

В `php.ini` прописан `sendmail_path: /urs/sbin/sendmail -i -t` (Все по умолчанию).

Exim4 работает и отправляет почту.

DKIM, SPF тоже все нормально.

Проблема:

Отправляю почту на сервес `mail-tester.com` и он мне говорит, что у меня нет rDNS записи. В итоге все мои письма летят в спам.

VPS куплен в одной конторе (reg.ru), домен в другой (GoDaddy). К домену привязана Яндекс.Почта для домена. Т.е. в MX-записях указано:

MX приоритет 10, @, сслылается на mx.yandex.net

Почта, работает, принимает.

Проблема только в rDNS или RTC.

Вывод нескольких команд:
`nslookup МОЙ_VPS_IP`

```
Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
666.666.666.666.in-addr.arpa       name = mysite.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Онлайн сервисы по проверке rDNS или RTC говорят, что у меня все нормально и показывают мой домен, который привязан к ip.

P.S. Если нужен вывод еще каких-либо команд, напишите.

**Яндекс только принимает почту (без их СМТП). VPS использую, чтобы отправлять.**

Comment: Может в мне в конфигах exim4 что добавить надо?

Comment: Домен куда делегирован? Почему smtp не используете?

Comment: Прочитайте про PHPMailer, настройте smtp yandex relay

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что здесь не биржа фрилансеров.

Comment: @alexander-barakin умоляю без занудства. Это просто эдакое спасибо

Comment: @andrew-hobbit. Домен просто для красивого названия нужен. Например я шлю с ololo@mydomain.com. Т.е. со своего пхп скрипта. =>  ololo@mydomain.com в нем отправитель. Письма идут уже на Яндекс.Почта для домена. Яндекс тут нужен только чтобы получать. VPS чтобы отправлять

Comment: Ну вот и я про то, что и отправлять можно с smtp, с одного ящика. Если что могу помочь с полной настройкой через ssh

Answer (score 2):

Буду считать, что вы настроили DKIM, SPF записи.

**rDNS** - Это преобразование вашего IP адреса в домен, если IP адрес с которого отправлено письмо не совпадает с доменным именем, ваше письмо попадает в спам. Так вот, У вашего домена на DNS серверах прописана А запись, которая связывает ваш домен с IP адресом сервера, где расположен ваш сайт. А **PTR** запись делает наоборот - связывает IP адрес с доменом.

В основном она необходима при отправке писем от имени вашего домена. Большинство почтовых серверов, прежде чем принять решение - поместить письмо во "Входящее" или отклонить как СПАМ, проверяют запись **PTR** у IP адреса сервера, с которого это письмо пришло. Если данная запись есть, и она совпадает с именем домена, от имени которого пришло письмо, то это будет являться одним из фактов для принятия положительного решения (что это письмо не СПАМ).

Т.к. **PTR** запись - это обратная запись, которая связывает IP адрес с доменом, то прописывать её должен владелец IP адреса, который назначен серверу, где расположен ваш сайт. **Иными словами, вам нужно обратиться на свой хостинг и попросить прописать PTR запись для IP адреса**. Регистратор доменов вам тут не поможет (если конечно вы не используете его хостинг).

Стоит прописывать **PTR** запись, если вы используете VPS или выделенный сервер. Если вы используете виртуальный хостинг, то, как правило, эта запись уже есть и указывает на имя сервера хостера.

Comment: Да проще по моей инструкции настроить и не париться, потому что он использует почту для домена на основе yandex. Да и заметь, он настроил Exim4, а почту пытается отправить от sendmail

Comment: @avparfiriev Ну в целом можно и через SMTP отправлять, я лично использую для отправки писем сервисы, которые этим занимаются, например Mailgun, очень удобное API и ничего настраивать кроме парочки записей в DNS не требуется, а он сам пытается доставить и проверяет доставку.

Comment: Ну вот и я про то, если человеку прикольно изобрести "Колесо"

Comment: Привет, спасибо, сейчас проверять буду. Отпишу

Comment: По поводу ценника - это наше такое "Спасибо", ок?

Comment: @mr.pob Данный ресурс не фриланс, спасибо здесь выражают через слова, выбор правильного ответа и голосование за репутацию поста.

Comment: @firepro представьте что тут этого не написано)) Просто заплатим и скажем спасибо, и проголосуем)

Comment: Ребят, проверил обратную DNS запись, она ссылает на мой домен. В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: @mr.pob Отправитель как домен? Отправляете с VPS? Проблема в том,что mail-tester говорит что rdns некорректный, когда присылаете ему письмо?

Answer (score 1):

Установка и настройка exim4

```
Apt-get install exim4
```

**Настройки для yandex.ru**

**Редактировать файл**

```
nano /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf
```

**Добавить в файл**

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames='server'
dc_smarthost='smtp.yandex.ru::587'
```

**Внесение данных о учетной записи**

**Редактировать файл**

```
nano /etc/exim4/passwd.client
```

**добавить в Файл**

```
smtp.yandex.ru:username@yandex.ru:password
```

**Сопоставление учетных записей и email-ящиков**

**Редактировать файл**

```
nano /etc/email-addresses
```

**Добавить/изменить в файле**

```
root: username@yandex.ru
www-data: username@yandex.ru
```

(В зависиости от пользователя под которым все это поднимается, необходиом добавить свое)

**Перезагрузка сервера почты**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/exim4 restart
```

При добавлении этой строки в Crontab, после перезагрузки - на почту mail@yandex.ru должно придти письмо от пользователя root(сопоставление имен выше), что сервер перезагружен

```
@reboot root sleep 60 && echo "Server reboot" | mail -s "server reboot" mail@yandex.ru
```

Если письмо пришло пришло, то EXIM4 настроен верно, дальше кури отправку из php (там все просто)

проверить из php  можно примерно так :

```
# cat testmail.php


<?php
mail('komu@mail.ru', 'тема письма', 'тело письма', 'From: ot.kogo@mail.ru');
?>


# php testmail.php
```

*В "от кого", нужно указать имя пользователя (смотри сопоставление имен пользователей и email адресов)*

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас проверять будем)

Comment: я не собираюсь через SMTP Yandex слать. Яндекс использую только для того, чтобы принимать почту. А слать письма хочу через свои VPS

Comment: А в чем разница, если ты все равно цепляешь домен к pdd?